# Javascript split() not working in second instance

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to write a function that returns an array of a syllable dictionary. I want there to be a third element in each index of the the array 'dictArray'. I'm not sure why lineSplit[1].split(' ') (the second instance) is not working. I get an error saying that lineSplit[1].split(' ') is undefined.

```
function formatData(data){
  var lines = data.toString().split("\n"),
       lineSplit,
       dictArray = [];

  lines.forEach(function(line){
    lineSplit = line.split("  ");
    lineSplit.concat([lineSplit[1].split(' ')]);
    dictArray.push(lineSplit);
  });

  return dictArray;
}
```

Edit - the data has a word two spaces then pronunciation of the word split with one space and then a new line.

this is an example of the data:

```
AARON  EH1 R AH0 N
AARON'S  EH1 R AH0 N Z
AARONS  EH1 R AH0 N Z
```

The error is a TypeError: cannot call method 'split' on undefined

Comment: What's in `data`? What's in `line` when the program fails?

Comment: Can you mention some sample data for the your parameter 'data'

Comment: In the line `lineSplit = line.split("  ");` is it intentional that the delimiter "  " has two spaces, and not one?  Or is that the bug?

Comment: this is on purpose, the word is separated by two spaces from the pronunciations - each of which is separated by only one space.

Comment: Can you confirm that `line` actually contains what you think it contains just before calling `split()` on it?

Comment: [I don't get an error](https://jsfiddle.net/jkecrfb9/)

Comment: I'm running this is node, could that be an issue?

Comment: definitely confirmed line contains what I think it contains.. when I run it as just lineSplit = line.split('  '); I get an array of arrays of length two - the words and the syllables.

Comment: The fiddle provided above by Andy seems to work.  So I'm supposing the issue is with the exact data you're using.  Is it possible the last line of your data has a trailing newline at the end with an empty line after it?  If so, that could cause `lines`, to have a spurious incorrectly formatted line after all the real data, which would cause the final iteration through your loop to fail on the second split.  That's just speculation, but it's all I can think of at the moment.  Maybe the best thing to do is see what `lineSplit` contains on the iteration of the loop where the error is occurring.

Comment: Found the error, there was a hidden new line at the end of the text file..

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in this code.

1. Your code is searching for `"  "` (double whitespace) split point per line. If it can not find any then there will be no `lineSplit[1]` hence `lineSplit[1].split(" ")` will throw TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined.
2. What are you really trying to accomplish? If you want to break down a paragraph into lines and replace repeated spaces with spaces just do it by `line.replace(/\s{2,}/g, " ")`